# How to make a Ramanmetrix model accept values other than the Raman spectra for input?

Tags: multiple-regression, software, chemometrics

I am working on a project to automatically evaluate Raman spectra from a production process.
It already works for some compounds with the chemometrics software Ramanmetrix (desktop version 0.5.0).
This are a few entries of the metadata table:

```
file    date    device  standard    type    batch   time    Glycerol    Product1    Product2    Acid2   Acid3   Ethanol
Sample1 Oktober 2022    Raman   FALSCH  3_S0    3   0,000   32,500  0,000   0,000   0,000   0,000   0,000
Sample2 Oktober 2022    Raman   FALSCH  3_S1    3   0,000   31,000  0,001   0,000   0,000   0,000   0,000
Sample3 Oktober 2022    Raman   FALSCH  3_S2    3   3,000   30,800  0,001   0,000   0,000   0,050   0,000
```

Up to now I used the Raman spectra from several reactor runs to build a multi-compenent PLS2 model. Now I want a pH meter as a second data source.

I already know that I can include just another column with the measured pH values in order to train the model with that additional value: https://docs.ramanmetrix.eu/documentation/Data.html#metadata-table
But if I would use that model it would try to predict pH values. But I want it to use my pH values as inputs not only for training but for later use of the model too. The pH value should be used together with the spectral intensity values as input and should predict concentrations.

--> How to have a model with Ramanmetrix accept values other than the Raman spectra for input? (If you know how to do it with R that would be another option.)

> This question ist neither about
>
> "programming" -> Ramanmetrix is a commercial software without source
> available,
>
> "debugging" -> The behavior of the software is according to its specifications,
>
> "routine operations" -> I try to find a way to use the software at the
> limits of its abilities as a chemometrics software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R package **pls** provides a formula interface, where additional input features can be specified as usual in R. Assuming your Raman spectra are in matrix in a single column* `$spectra` in data.frame** `traindata`, and the pH measurements in an additional column `$pH`, the formula is:

`plsr(Y ~ spectra + pH, data = traindata)`

---

Example:

Unfortunately, **pls** does not come with example data with additional input feature columns. But for the sake of the demonstration, we can "borrow" one of the features from the `$sensory` matrix.

I `unclass()` the `syrup` column to have the resulting column a normal numeric column vector. Otherwise, i.e., keeping the AsIs protection, it would be a 1-column matrix. That doesn't change anything in terms of how `plsr()` calculations, but it is the structure you'd get if you add a `$pH` numeric column to your data.

```r
library(pls)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'pls'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     loadings

oliveoil$syrup <- unclass(oliveoil$sensory [, 6])
oliveoil$sensory <- oliveoil$sensory [, -6]

str(oliveoil)
#> 'data.frame':    16 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ chemical: 'AsIs' num [1:16, 1:5] 0.73 0.19 0.26 0.67 0.52 0.26 0.24 0.3 0.35 0.19 ...
#>   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#>   .. ..$ : chr [1:16] "G1" "G2" "G3" "G4" ...
#>   .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "Acidity" "Peroxide" "K232" "K270" ...
#>  $ sensory : 'AsIs' num [1:16, 1:5] 21.4 23.4 32.7 30.2 51.8 40.7 53.8 26.4 65.7 45 ...
#>   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#>   .. ..$ : chr [1:16] "G1" "G2" "G3" "G4" ...
#>   .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "yellow" "green" "brown" "glossy" ...
#>  $ syrup   : num  50.3 51.7 45.4 47.8 46.5 52.2 45.2 51.8 48.3 52.8 ...

PLS <- plsr(sensory ~ chemical + syrup, data = oliveoil) 
summary(PLS)
#> Data:    X dimension: 16 6 
#>  Y dimension: 16 5
#> Fit method: kernelpls
#> Number of components considered: 6
#> TRAINING: % variance explained
#>         1 comps  2 comps  3 comps  4 comps  5 comps  6 comps
#> X         87.50    99.78    99.93   100.00   100.00   100.00
#> yellow    31.05    38.82    61.10    63.33    67.32    67.33
#> green     23.78    33.24    57.57    58.94    62.23    62.79
#> brown     57.02    61.46    64.53    70.47    77.91    79.26
#> glossy    45.40    46.77    52.56    53.95    54.07    54.24
#> transp    44.40    44.73    51.91    52.17    52.17    52.88
coef(PLS)
#> , , 6 comps
#> 
#>                       yellow       green        brown       glossy
#> chemicalAcidity   -25.891768   19.163932   -8.1196335   -3.9751733
#> chemicalPeroxide    2.988711   -4.085759    0.7503641   -0.3045587
#> chemicalK232      -26.377490   13.871625    3.2495366   -9.1464594
#> chemicalK270     -286.890402  446.018506   65.6440941   -3.4866089
#> chemicalDK        188.685249 1536.732476 -532.8797069 -225.9279457
#> syrup              -3.673334    4.697099    0.2390744   -0.3489226
#>                         transp
#> chemicalAcidity    -3.84939170
#> chemicalPeroxide   -0.01070925
#> chemicalK232       -4.11961973
#> chemicalK270      -47.36210317
#> chemicalDK       -618.53901213
#> syrup              -1.16178028
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

* It is not strictly necessary to have the spectra in a `matrix`, `plsr()` can calculate with `data.frame` columns as well, but matrix calculations are much faster. Also, the formula description is much cleaner that way. You can find a short discussion in `vignette("pls-manual")` section 4.2.

** or any other class that can be evaluated into a `data.frame` by `model.frame()`

---

As for Ramanmetrix, I understand the linked documentation to say you cannot specify a metadata column to be an additional input feature.

Thus I guess, your only chance to add the pH as input feature with the current software version would be to add it to the spectra (as a fake wavelength). That however, would interfere with at least some of the preprocessing options. Sounds like a very deep rabbit hole to me.

Have you contacted the developers and what did they answer?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas regarding R. The devs of Ramanmetrix answered in a similiar way: additional input is currently not directly supported. I think it is an interesting hack adding the pH to the spectra.